# Physics is not rendering, It only renders when I bake it

Tags: cloth-simulation

So basically I was making a flag simulation and it sticks to the initial frame and it doesn’t simulate anything for the whole render.(Unless I bake it). Is this meant to be or is something wrong, Please help.

Comment: Depending on your setup this is normal. Always bake simulations before rendering. They have to be calculated anyway so why not beforehand in a controled cached fashion.

Comment: Yeah I’ll do that, Thanks :)